# Правильный откат merg-а в git

Tags: git

Есть ветка релиза (release 1.0), также есть фича какой-то доработки (feature). Решили включить feature в этот релиз: слили feature в release, а затем в какой-то момент передумали и решили пока не включать. Для того чтобы поправить теперь ветку release мы импользуем revert коммита слияния feature в release, таким образом становится вроде бы все хорошо. Но, когда релиз протестирован, мы его вливаем в master и от мастера создаем новую ветку след релиза (release 2.0). Пытаемся в release 2.0 влить нашу старую feature, и видим что она вливается некорректно - поскольку в истории ветки release 2.0 есть коммит revert, который отменяет доработки этой feature. Подскажите как делают умные люди процесс отката слияния чтобы не было таких проблем?

Comment: Можно выполнить реверт реверта попробовать, сталкивался с этой бедой давно и уже не уверен, поможет ли. Стараюсь больше мержи не ревертить просто.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#r_reverse_commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, разработка этой "feature" происходила в отдельном бранче, который вы замерджили в основной, скажем в master. Вы можете сделать rebase коммита, следующего после коммита слияния, в этом основном бранче, таким образом, чтобы его "родителем" стал не данный коммит слияния, а предыдущий коммит в бранче master.  Сделать это можно в интерактивном режиме командой `git rebase -r -i hash_of_commit` где "hash_of_commit" - это хеш коммита до коммита слияния в бранче master.

Предположим начальная картина коммитов у вас такая и вы хотите отменить коммит слияния "Merge branch 'feature1'":

[image: начальная картина коммитов]

Я запустил команду `git rebase -r -i 6c17bde4e83b6129e35499089c88c30bc17c7bc1` где хеш относится к "3rd commit". Хеш можно указывать неполностью. После запуска этой команды будет открыт текстовый редактор, по умолчанию vi, со следующим содержимым:

[image: начало ребейса]

На строке, относящейся к коммиту слияния, под строкой "reset onto", я заменяю `merge -C` на `drop` или просто `d`, а затем сохраняю этот текст и завершаю работу редактора.

[image: дром мерджа]

Обратите внимание, что в редактируемом тексте все коммиты располагаются в обратном (привычному из `git log`) порядке - самый новый коммит внизу.

Когда вы завершите работу редактора Git начнёт идти по списку коммитов и производить с ними определённые действия. В нашем случае Git удалит коммит слияния и дальше заново отработает (pick) последующие коммиты, которых у нас лишь один. При этом возможны конфликты, ведь base, то есть основа, у этих коммитов теперь другая. Разрешать конфликты нужно так же, как конфликты во време слияния. То есть редактируете конфликтные файлы, делаете им `git add` и затем запускаете `git rebase --continue`. И так, возможно, несколько раз. В конечном итоге изначальная картина коммитов изменится на такую:

[image: конечная картина коммитов]

В итоге вы изменили историю, пока что лишь локально. Если коммит слияния успел попасть на сервер, вы можете изменить историю и там, запустив команду `git push -f` из бранча master. Если вы используете Bitbucket или что-то похожее, предварительно убедитесь, что у вас есть права на push в master. После этого все разработчики должны удалить свои локальные бранчи master и заново забрать его с сервера:

```
git branch -d master
git fetch
git checkout master
```

Всё это нетривиально и потенциально опасно, поэтому в будущем старайтесь не ошибаться с решением что и куда мерджить.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!